# Critique: Logo for a food company

Tags: logo, critique

I designed this logo for a company called Finger Food, which provides finger food for other companies and events like parties, but mainly for companies (like the food your company gives you on Valentine’s Day). It’s all about good food and health, even if it’s fried. I am not a graphic designer, but I am designing their web, so I have to do this too.

Is this logo portraying what I’ve told you about the company?

If not, what would you recommend to change?

[image: The logo have a square with #ffffcc fill color and a outline of 4pt of a #666633 color, inside have two F in a #cccc33 color and are united]

Comment: It feels haphazard. Can you explain the intent of the overlapping shapes? In terms of legibility, the lower F gets a bit lost.

Comment: I get neither finger nor food from *anything* in that logo. In fact, I'd have *no clue* it represented a company having anything to do with food. Not that that is inherently a bad thing, but you asked. And I agree that overall it seems very haphazard and without purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reviews,  I didn't notice the f was lost but now I see @DA01, :( Yeah i was having that feeling too, I was trying with different shapes for me it looks just okey, I think that I've need a little bit more time to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal benchmark for Logos: Draw your logo with a pen (without seeing your draft). I feel that's a good way to check if you got a **unique, memorable shape**. The second, of course, is to fax it to someone and see if more than a black square appears. Thats good for checking if your logo works in black and white.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above comments, my major concern pertains to the various angles present in the font and design. The general design scheme is all aobut outlines; however, the bottom portion, top left portion and top right portions of the "F"s have different angles. This makes for a disruptive visual.

My opinion is that the top right portion's angle should guide the remainder of the visual(wherever angles are present). You could transform an object placed over this angle to discover the angle's value.